# MS Access query on DATEVALUE

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm trying to run a query that only included recordsa after a certain date, but the date is in text format.

I've tried using lots of different methods but I can't get it to work

these return 'Data type mismatch'

```
SELECT  DateValue([BasicStartDate]) AS [DATE]
WHERE (((DateValue([BasicStartDate]))>=#5/15/2017#));

WHERE (((DateValue([BasicStartDate]))>=2017-5-15));

WHERE (((DateValue([BasicStartDate]))>='2017-5-15'));
```

I've aslo tried using cdate but get issues with invalid use of NULL when ever i try to put a where query on the result - despite there being no nulls in the returned column before applying the where query.

Comment: What format is `[BasicStartDate]` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you get *Invalid use of Null*, Nulls are present. So filter those out:

```
SELECT
    DateValue([BasicStartDate]) AS [DATE]
FROM 
    YourTable
WHERE 
    [BasicStartDate] Is Not Null 
    And
    DateValue([BasicStartDate]) >= #5/15/2017#;
```